# code signing of iPhone application

Tags: iphone

1)   i developed one application.. it is working fine in simulator. does it work in real
     iPhone with out any modification..

2)
   a) when i select in xcode projectmenu -> SetActiveSDK -> Device-iPhone OS 2.2  getting one
      error. but i can't see what is the error, how to solve this ?.
   b) if it is not working with Device -iPhone OS SDK, is it work on the real iPhone.?

pls help , thanx and regards.

Comment: "code singings," I love that. I sing the code electric. Editing that to "signing."

Answer (score 1):

Good job on your app. It's a good sign that it works in the simulator, but you never know if it will work on the device until you try. Some things will be faster on the device and many things will be slower. There are other differences. It's possible to have your app crash on the device but not on the sim, or the other way around. It's even more common to have memory leaks on one but not the other. XCode lets you debug on either and run the code tools on either.

Signing is a bit of a nightmare. It's easy to mess it up. Follow the instructions carefully. If you think you've messed up your project beyond hope, start a new project and move your source and assets over to it.

At some point you'll have everything working, then you'll turn off your computer or something and you'll get a message that you don't have a valid device connected. Reboot your iPhone when that happens.

Be warned that it's even hairier signing your code for the App store.

Just stay calm and keep trying. Also, ask on Apple's boards. Many people have gone through the trama and shared your pain. Good luck.